# Getting a message when a child control receives focus

Tags: winapi, windows-messages

I have a control that contains another control inside. The inner control sometimes snatches focus from other controls and I need to place a watch on this and change focus back. I'm subclassing the out control (can't subclass the inner one), and I'm listening for the `WM_SETFOCUS` message, but this only occurs when I click one of the controls. When the focus is snatched by the inner control itself, I'm getting nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need `WM_KILLFOCUS`? [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: WM_KILLFOCUS works fine for the control that focus is being snatched from, but I use this setup as a user control in several places, and I don't want to have to place a WM_KILLFOCUS watch on each one of them.

Comment: *"Snatching focus"* and *"change focus back"* is most likely the wrong solution. If you want to prevent a control from gaining focus you simply disable the control.

Comment: I agree, this is a bad solution, but it is the only one I can use.

Comment: It is not a *solution* - this really **is** your problem. Solve that and you won't need to stack another hack on top of a hack.